# Remove unrequired key-value pairs- Javascript Array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I'm working on a Aura component and getting below array as
response.getReturnValue() from server

```
[{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ24AI","Product2Id":"01t8W000005n3SPQAY","Product2":{"Name":"*à confirmer","Id":"01t8W000005n3SPQAY"}},
{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ74AI","Product2Id":"01t8W000005mt3JQAQ","Product2":{"Name":"1101001603S","Id":"01t8W000005mt3JQAQ"}}]
```

I need only 2 key-value pair(s) out of this -

```
Id, Name
```

So basically I need a new array with below format to proceed further

```
[{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ24AI","Name":"*à confirmer"},
{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ74AI","Name":"1101001603S"}]
```

I've already tried most of the javascript method showing online but no help.
Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **Array.map()** method to transform the original array into a new array with only the desired key-value pairs.

```
const response = [{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ24AI","Product2Id":"01t8W000005n3SPQAY","Product2":{"Name":"*à confirmer","Id":"01t8W000005n3SPQAY"}}, {"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ74AI","Product2Id":"01t8W000005mt3JQAQ","Product2":{"Name":"1101001603S","Id":"01t8W000005mt3JQAQ"}}];

const result = response.map(({ Id, Product2: { Name } }) => ({ Id, Name }));

console.log(result);
```

The map() method will iterate over each object in the original array. For each object, we're creating a new object with only the Id and Name properties that we want. We then return this new object from the map() function, which builds up the new array for us.

Comment: Hey welcome to SFSE! Thanks for your contributions, keep it up and see you around!

Comment: Thanks Raul, will try!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get desired JSON result:

```js
const products = [
    {
        Id: "0QLDM000000gpJ24AI",
        Product2Id: "01t8W000005n3SPQAY",
        Product2: { Name: "*à confirmer", Id: "01t8W000005n3SPQAY" },
    },
    {
        Id: "0QLDM000000gpJ74AI",
        Product2Id: "01t8W000005mt3JQAQ",
        Product2: { Name: "1101001603S", Id: "01t8W000005mt3JQAQ" },
    },
];

// Pass a function to map
const modifiedProducts = products.map((p) => {
    return { Name: p.Product2.Name, Id: p.Id };
});

console.log(modifiedProducts);
// Expected output: Array [{"Name":"*à confirmer","Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ24AI"},{"Name":"1101001603S","Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ74AI"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
But I want the outer ID value(s) not the Product2 ones.

Like 
[{"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ24AI","Name":"*à confirmer"}, {"Id":"0QLDM000000gpJ74AI","Name":"1101001603S"}]

Id's are outer Id's, not the inner ones.

Comment: Such a life saviour. Thanks a lot.